# Is there a way to granulary control the animation properties on a CSS element?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have this code:

```
transition: all 0.35s;
transition-delay: 0.25s;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.79,0,.46,1);
```

But it turned out to be problematic if I add more properties that I wanna animate, so I'm looking to do something like:

```
transition: transform 0.35s/*duration*/ 0.25s /*delay*/ cubic-bezier(.79,0,.46,1),
            opacity 0.25s/*duration*/ 1s /*delay*/ ease-in ;
```

I looked at the short-hand properties but can't quite find the right combo.

Comment: cubic-bezier is as advanced as transform-timing-function gets. If you want more you have to resort to @keyframes (css-animations)

Comment: And if you want even more there are many nice javascript-libraries. Such as [bouncejs](http://bouncejs.com), [velocityjs](http://velocityjs.org), [animejs](http://animejs.com) or when you need to go full out [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap). I personally think all of those are easier to use (and much less verbose) than pure css-animations (well, bounce only creates the css-animations for you), but I suppose it does help if you are familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you want is a css **animation** not a css transition. Transitions are for creating a smooth transition from one state to another while animations allow you to define more complex behavior by changing css properties.

It would look something like this:

```
element {
  animation-name: yourAnimationName;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.79,0,.46,1);
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

@keyframes yourAnimationName {
   // here you define which css properties to animate
}
```

You can either define the keyframes using from and to:

```
@keyframes yourAnimationName {
    from { background-color: red; }
    to { background-color: yellow; }
}
```

or you can define multiple keyframes using percentages (at what percentage of the entire animation):

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    25%  {background-color: yellow;}
    50%  {background-color: blue;}
    100% {background-color: green;}
}
```

You also probably wont need your cubic-bezier timing function if you use keyframes as percentages.

I recommend reading a bit about css animations [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Comment: Argh, of course there is, but I was hoping for a more...elegant appraoch.